# Как добавить стиль родителю у которого дочерний элемент input:checked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть несколько таких чекбоксов:

```
<div class="radiobtn_container">
    <input id="greenhouse_width-1" type="radio" name="greenhouse_width" value="0" checked="" type="radio">
    <label for="greenhouse_width-1">Все</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobtn_container">
        <input id="greenhouse_width-2" type="radio" name="greenhouse_width" value="2" checked="" type="radio">
        <label for="greenhouse_width-2">Второй чекбокс</label>
    </div>
```

При смене чек-бокса можно менять стили таким образом:

```
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background: #ffe0a6;
}
```

Но как поменять стиль родителя `radiobtn_container` ?
Нужно что-бы при смене активного checkbox'a менялся его родитель.
jQuery или JS не важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let radioSelector = '.radiobtn_container input[type="radio"]';

$(document).on('change', radioSelector, function() {
    $(radioSelector).closest('.radiobtn_container').removeClass('test');
    $(this).closest('.radiobtn_container').addClass('test');
});

// $(radioSelector).eq(0).trigger('click'); --- можно использовать вместо кода ниже, если нужно поставить check на самом первом элементе
$(radioSelector).each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
        $(this).closest('.radiobtn_container').addClass('test');
});
```

```css
.form_radio_btn input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background: #ffe0a6;
}

.test {
   border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="radiobtn_container">
    <input id="greenhouse_width-1" type="radio" name="greenhouse_width" value="0" type="radio">
    <label for="greenhouse_width-1">Все</label>
</div>
<div class="radiobtn_container">
        <input id="greenhouse_width-2" type="radio" name="greenhouse_width" value="2" checked="" type="radio">
        <label for="greenhouse_width-2">Второй чекбокс</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Упал на блоки с "checked", но почему при нажатии на другие "checked" с инпутов не перебрасывается на активные? А следовательно и стили тоже...

Comment: @Alexandr не понял вопрос.

Comment: @Alexandr сформулируйте вопрос полностью пожалуйста. и Корректно. Что у вас есть, что вы делаете и каков результат должен быть. Можете добавить больше разметки и т.д.

Comment: Добавил инфу в вопрос

Comment: Если в вашем примере смотреть. То если чекбокса будет, например, три штуки. Нужно что-бы рамка была у активного в настоящий момент чекбокса. А при загрузке страницы был активен именно первый.

Comment: @Alexandr посмотрите ещё раз ответ

Comment: @Alexandr чтобы активный был первым - стоит атрибут "checked" поставить только ему)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён)

Comment: @Alexandr кстати, если вам нужно реально в самом начале кликнуть первый, то вместо последнего кода, где идёт проход циклом, достаточно триггернуть событие на нём вот так: `$(radioSelector).eq(0).trigger('click');`. Но, конечно, проще сразу расставить атрибут `checked` как надо только там где нужно)))